# JavaFX: Could not find or load main class only on linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, javafx

I've developed a program in Windows with Java(FX) using Intellij Idea and that worked just fine, I then exported the artifact (jar) and there was no problem running it on Windows (both with the console and double clicking it).

I've then copied it to my Ubuntu VM, but there it says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
```

This is the Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main
```

The JAR file structure looks like this:

```
test.jar
--- META-INF
--- --- MANIFEST.MF
--- org
--- --- json
--- --- --- // json library
--- sample
--- --- Contacts.class
--- --- Controller.class
--- --- Main.class
--- --- sample.fxml
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu, like Debian, has a separate package for OpenJFX (OpenJDK's implementation of JavaFX). Why this is the case, when JavaFX is an integral part of the JRE - I do not know, but your problem should be solved by installing the OpenJFX package:

```
# aptitude install openjfx
```

(or using any other package manager), or by using Oracle's JRE.

Comment: Issuing the above command (had to use `sudo`) did not fix the problem for me, under Ubuntu 19.10. Strange that the jar works ok on Mac but not Ubuntu.

Comment: Installing openjfx on its own did not solve the problem for me also on Ubuntu 19.10. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130740/286701) written by @abulka below contains the full fix.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact problem myself after developing a demo jar called `javafx1.jar` using IntelliJ on the Mac and wanting to run it on Linux. After installing the jdk on Ubuntu 19.10 with `sudo apt install default-jdk` I also needed to, as @Itai answered, install OpenJFX, which no longer comes bundled with openjdk 11. I used the regular apt command:

```
sudo apt install openjfx
```

**Critical next step: -->**  Then as this stackoverflow answer by [@Lotfi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319350/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-application-main-caused-by-java-lang-n/57946745#57946745) advises, when running your jar you need to pass the path to those OpenJFX modules. This is what the [official docs say](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), too. So for running `javafx1.jar` you say:

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar javafx1.jar
```

which is an annoyingly long line to have to use. You can shorten it to specify all modules in that directory using the `ALL-MODULE-PATH` parameter:

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar javafx1.jar
```

P.S. You can find where the javafx module path is on your system by running `dpkg-query -L javafx`.

### Why java's error message is dumb

The message `Could not find or load main class sample.Main` is actually misleading in this case and has nothing to do with not being able to find `sample.Main` itself. Dilligently checking the contents of the jar with `jar -tf javafx1.jar` and checking that the path `sample.Main` is in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, as you did - offers no clues.

Because `sample.Main` depends on JavaFX and because the latter could not be found, java mischeviously tells you that `sample.Main` is the problem, rather than reporting that a dependency is missing - not good behaviour by java IMO.  You may be able to use `jdeps` to isolate the problem, e.g. `jdeps -v javafx1.jar` tells me what is missing.

So

```
jdeps -v javafx2.jar | grep "not found"
```

lists that I'm missing stuff, whereas

```
jdeps --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH -v javafx1.jar | grep "not found"
```

says nothing is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution is to use Oracle JRE on Debians. I observed the same behavior when I built my JavaFX project using InteliJ Idea JavaFX Packager on Windows. Building a project with ordinary Maven did not cause this issue.