# Could not find or load main class when running JAR on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jar

I ran my javafx jar in windows os. It worked in windows.

But , when I run in ubuntu it comes an error like this

```
Error : Could not find or load main class
Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDeffounderror javafx/application/Application
```

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcgQF.png)

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319350/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-application-main-caused-by-java-lang-n

Comment: Or any of the gazillion results a google search for that error returned...

Comment: Are you using the same versions of java on both systems? What are they?

Comment: You may not have installed JavaFX on the ubuntu system.